# How to increase the internal resources to SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting this error when i try to ran my query.
"Query Processor ran out of internal resources".

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser or ServerFault. Not sure which is more appriopriate.

Comment: It is likely that this error is due to lack of memory on your database server. Whats the memory utilization of your DB server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out one of 4 possible answers from [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?mode=r&query=%22The+query+processor+ran+out+of+internal+resources%22&spid=global&catalog=LCID%3D1033&1033comm=1&ast=25&ast=28&res=20)

Or do you have a massive `IN` clause?

Comment: i have some 180 columns in my select statement after join and all, and when i used conditions like "where eid = 1" it is working fine. But if i used like "where eid in (1,2,3)" it is giving me the error.